# Avoiding a double serialize/deserialize

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF webservice that acts as a proxy between a WCF windows service and a client interface.  This is done so that our program can have a central "state" server, while the webservices can be distributed.

Ideally i would like to cut out the middle IIS hosted WCF webservice serialization and feed the bytes sent by the client directly to the windows service via IIS.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using [NLB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Load_Balancing_Services) directly? I think that a cluster will do a better job distributing requests than a proxy WCF service.

Comment: because the initial client request must go through IIS.  the WCF webservice is just there to relay the request to the central state server.

Comment: Right, but *why* must it go through IIS?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but you'll want to not use WCF in the middle.  The level of difficulty depends on the technology you're using for your transport.  For example, if you're using BasicHttp (good ol' SOAP) you can write a proxy in ASP.NET that routes the bytes from the client to the server via an HttpWebRequest.

You also could consider installing a reverse proxy on your web boxes to route your WCF requests through to your central web service.